# How to Cycle Through a Series on ICON Buttons via jQuery click() Function

Tags: jquery, click

I have a grid of about 20 rows and 10 columns.

In each cell intersection I want to be able to click an ICON image that I have displayed and be able to cycle through a series of 3 graphics image ICONS on each click, without there being an end necessarily. In other words, the cycle can continue on for as long as I click. There are 120 instances on the presence of the ICON buttons.

Here is a snippit of my HTML:

```
<td class="rights"><img src="../images/button1.png" alt="First of 3 ICONS" class="button" /></td>
```

The corresponding CSS is insignificant to the scenario.

Here is a snippit of my jQuery:

```
// jQuery Functions
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Toggle ICONS
    $('img.button').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('src') == '../images/button1.png') $(this).closest('img.arcButton').attr('src', '../images/button2.png');
        else if ($(this).attr('src') == '../images/button2.png') $(this).closest('img.arcButton').attr('src', '../images/button3.png');
        else if ($(this).attr('src') == '../images/button3.png') $(this).closest('img.arcButton').attr('src', '../images/button1.png');
    }); // end Toggle ICONS
}) // end jQuery Functions
```

My ICONs are `button1.png`, `button2.png`, and `button3.png`

Thanks for helping

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is a carousel. Check out some plugins like caroufredsel (http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) and jcarousel (http://www.jcarousel.com/09/index.php), etc. Google search "jquery carousel" for more options.

Comment: Check [This](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Comment: well, actually what I am going to end up doing is associate the button with a textbox value as part of my input form such that when button1 is showing the form value with be "V". When button2 is clicked and showing the form value with be "M". And when if/when button3 is clicked and chowing the form value will be NULL. But I can handle the form values later. I want to start by being able to cycle through each ICON

Comment: Hmm...the carousel is not what I am looking for. I want the ICON buttons to switch in position. In other words, the static image changes right in place from one button to the next. I do not have the space nor the desire to have the images side-by-side in a carousel fashion.

Comment: I amended my jQuery because I was able to force the next button the appear. I just need to be able to figure out what ICON is currently being displayed and then cycle to the next button. Bear in mind that when the page loads, any one of the 3 buttons will show in the cell intersection based on the value pre-loaded into my web form (from my database).

Comment: I got it to work...see my jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the jQuery solution I can up with, tested, and got to work.

```
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '../images/button1.png') $(this).closest('img.arcButton').attr('src', '../images/button2.png');
    else if ($(this).attr('src') == '../images/button2.png') $(this).closest('img.arcButton').attr('src', '../images/button3.png');
    else if ($(this).attr('src') == '../images/button3.png') $(this).closest('img.arcButton').attr('src', '../images/button1.png');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ok, I revised my answer @JSW189 -- thanks for helping me use SO better